# This page or app is using an unsupported version of the Yammer platform

Tags: sharepoint, office365, yammer

We are on Office 365, and use sharepoint online with Yammer for social.  Several months back we started getting the error mentioned above when the Yammer app for Sharepoint would load.

I have viewed the information in **KB2966312** at https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2966312?wa=wsignin1.0

However, neither of the remedies mentioned in this article appear.

For example: In 1.A.3 it says:

> Locate the Yammer App for SharePoint, and then click update.

I have no option to update there, so I proceed to 1.B where it has the following instructions:

> If you don’t see the update link on the Yammer App for SharePoint,
>   follow these steps: Click the ellipsis (…) next to the Yammer App for
>   SharePoint. Click About to update the app. After the update process is
>   complete, click the ellipsis (…) next to the Yammer App for SharePoint
>   to make sure that the version is greater than 1.0.0.6.

On the about page, I see version 1.0.0.7, but I am still getting the errors.

I have attempted to remove the Yammer app, then re-adding it after many weeks, but nothing I do will get this app to update.

I would appreciate any guidance.